# Youtube music - scrolling effect - CollapsingToolbarLayout - toolbar fade in/out

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement an effect like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvG0z.jpg

Is there any simple way to implement this effect by using android framework components?

I found a component called `collapsingtoolbarlayout` it can achieve this effect perhaps. But i'm not sure how to implement.

can someone give me a tips? thank you!

Comment: I can't say about `CollapsingToolbar` as I've not used it but I would've done it by setting-up a custom `ToolBar`, animating its background's `alpha` value from the `OnScrollListener` of the `RecyclerView`. I'd done similar thing to other widgets.

Comment: For `CollapsingToolBar`, you can look at these Github repos: [First](https://github.com/arsan-official/collapsing-toolbar), [Second](https://github.com/kitek/android-collapsing-toolbar) and [Third](https://github.com/cognice/collapsing-toolbar). These contain complete implementation of this `CollapsingToolBar`, you can check them out.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. @LalitFauzdar I think this way(custom toolbar) that will be simple way to reach it. I'll try it. I'm not familiar with `CollapsingToolBar ` I'll attempt, thanks man.